# Is it dangerous for views to directly use domain models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've used an EF code-first approach to define my DB structure.  Currently, I am passing the EF entity classes directly into some of my views in an MVC application.  This makes it easy to populate and save the views because I can just directly have a repository give me my populated EF class, and if my controller receives an EF entity class in a postback, I can (if validation is OK) pass that straight through to the repository to save it.  However, is this potentially a security risk?  If there are properties on an entity class that I don't want modified, could the client submit those properties back as part of the postback and modify them anyway?  For example, say I have a view to edit a user to which I pass this EF model:

```
public class User {
    [Required]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
}
```

I might expose `Firstname`, `Surname`, and `DOB` as editable form fields, but I don't want the user to be able to set `IsDisabled` and disable their account.  What's the best way to guard against this?  Perhaps one should only use domain models in views directly when one thinks it's alright for *every* property persisted by that domain model to be settable by the user, or when one is just using that domain model to display things, rather than save things back to a data store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just come across this post:
http://www.codethinked.com/ASPNET-MVC-Think-Before-You-Bind

It gives several approaches to dealing with this problem, but the one I've chosen in my project is a variant on the `UpdateModel()` approach.  That approach relies on retrieving the updateable object from the DB, then using `UpdateModel()` to set *only the fields you want to update* on that object.  My approach is for the repository's `Update` method to take a lambda ("update strategy") that is responsible for setting the fields you want to update:

```
public bool UpdateUser(User updatedUser, Action<User, User> updateStrategy) {
    // Retrieve User via updatedUser.UserID...
    // Update it using updateStrategy(retrievedUser, updatedUser)...
    // Save the updated retrievedUser to DB
}

// ...
// To call the update method:
repoUser.UpdateUser(updatedUser, (existingUser, updatedUser) => {
    existingUser.Firstname = updatedUser.Firstname;
    existingUser.Surname = updatedUser.Surname;
    existingUser.DOB = updatedUser.DOB;
});
```

In both cases, it guards against updating any fields you don't want to, whether or not they were posted to the action method.  Of course, the nefarious client could modify the hidden `UserID` field, but I don't think that needs to be guarded against; it just changes which user is being updated, and if your system lets them update a user they shouldn't have permission to, that would seem to be a security flaw in and of itself.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can be dangerous to pass Entities directly to your view.  Technically, the problem is when you model bind to entities directly.

Yes, it's very possible for the situation you presented to occur.  Even worse.  Suppose you pas a User object, then an attacker could submit a post value to do something like set IsAdmin true, or alter the roles assigned to the user.

Of course, all this depends on the user knowing (or being able to guess) the structure of your data.  That may not be as difficult as it seems, since we often have tell-tale signs in our generated HTML that give hints.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1) Use view models.  The view model only contains the data that's allowed in the view.  You can also control what data gets copied back into the entity model.

2) you can use the `[Bind]` attribute to specify exclusions and inclusions to white-list and black-list various properties.

I prefer using the first approach, since it's much harder to forget to white-list or black-list something (especially if you change something later and forget to update the list everywhere you bind it).  I also feel like `[Bind]` is cheating and encourages sloppy design.

Answer (score 3):

You are not really supposed to use your entity models as view models, and I think your example here really highlights that better than I have seen anywhere else.

If your controller accepted, upon post, a `User` then yes, you would be exposing that data to be posted there. If you mapped the posted user directly without checking for invalid submission then you would have persisted the problem into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a view model.  That way, you're protected both from someone attempting to access a non-visible property, like your `IsDisabled` as it wouldn't be in the view model at all, and you decouple your domain from your presentation layer.  If you ever needed to expand on your EF entities (more properties, more relationships, whatever), your view models likely wouldn't need to change.